# django social-registration redirect url sometimes /social/setup and sometimes /accounts/profile . Why?

Tags: django

In django social registration, usually it redirects to

```
   /social/setup .
```

So i have written a view pointing to that url . But, why some times it redirects to

```
      /accounts/profile
```

Why its happening like this ?

Answer (score 8):

Django redirects to /accounts/profile when it doesn't know were to redirect to. You can change this behaviour by setting `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```